# Sort an enumerated list by the value

Tags: python, list, enumerate

MWE:

```
list1 = [2,5,46,23,9,78]
list1 = list(enumerate(list1))
```

Now suppose I want to sort this list by the index 1, i.e. by the original list1, in say, ascending order.
How do I do that?

I would like something that could then give me both the indexes and the values.

```
list2 = sorted(list1[1], key=float)
```

Comment: If it's an option, consider sorting the list before enumerating it: `list(enumerate(sorted(list1)))`, unless you intend to keep a reference to the original index, in which case this does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sort with `item[1]` as key:

```
>>> list2 = sorted(list1, key=lambda x:x[1])
>>> list2
[(0, 2), (1, 5), (4, 9), (3, 23), (2, 46), (5, 78)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(list1, key=itemgetter(1))
[(0, 2), (1, 5), (4, 9), (3, 23), (2, 46), (5, 78)]
```

By providing a function of one argument to [`key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) we are specifying a comparison key for list elements used by `sorted`. [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is a nice functional wrapper around item getter operator `[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in the whole list (not just the first element), and use a lambda function to sort on the value - `x[1]`.

```
>>> list1 = [2,5,46,23,9,78]
>>> list2 = list(enumerate(list1))
>>> list2
[(0, 2), (1, 5), (2, 46), (3, 23), (4, 9), (5, 78)]
>>> list3 = sorted(list2, key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> list3
[(0, 2), (1, 5), (4, 9), (3, 23), (2, 46), (5, 78)]
```